# Hydrogen music making software

Tags: software-center, music

Is it possible to include hydrogen to this ubuntu distribution? because i want to make music and i cannot find that program from this distribution repositories.

-KK

Comment: http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/Repositories

Answer (score 2):

[`hydrogen`](http://hydrogen-music.org/) is in the [repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=hydrogen):

just open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and insert `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y hydrogen`, type your root-password (no characters will be displayed) and just wait till executed!

Answer (score 1):

The `hydrogen` package is in the Ubuntu archive already.